# How to find out user is at desktop instead of start screen or another store app UI at Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

As we know, at windows 8 if user is at start screen or another store app (metro app) UI, the dialog at the desktop won't be visible to user. We are adding some toast notification capability at our application by following [Sending toast notifications from desktop apps sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/sending-toast-notifications-71e230a2). I am able to get it working. However if user is already at the desktop, we don't want to send out the toast notification. So it would mean that we need to be able to detect if user is current at desktop or not. Somehow I didn't find any API by searching on internet. Could someone let me know how to do so? Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't know or certain, but I would be very surprised if you could do that.

Comment: Thanks, It looks like that this is impossible since I haven't got any answer on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A toast notification can't know in what context the user is located, so this is not possible.

Comment: Thanks. Could a win32 desktop app detect where user is at desktop or not?